# Symfony2 - How to create a new OneToOne relation without effecting database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have a BlogBundle and I want to add a thread to my posts (using FOSCommentBundle) but following the FOS documentation I have to provide the thread ID. The problem is that all my older posts has the thread property set to NULL, what is the best way to associate a new thread to my older posts ? If possible, I would not have to change the FOSThreadController.

```
/**
 * @var \ACME\CommentBundle\Thread $thread
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ACME\CommentBundle\Entity\Thread", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $thread;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write [command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html) to find all the posts with *thread == null* and create thread for it.

Comment: yes, you definately need to fix up your data. those legacy stuff will cause you big trouble (exceptions in templates, as you can't link back to thread overview.. )

Answer (score 0):

define mapping in your doctrine/
your_entity.orm.xml/yml too.